# Unable to locate task :shadowJar for a subproject despite of configuring it in a root project

Tags: gradle, multi-project, shadowjar

I have a project structured like

```
NetworkASCtoSocket
./client
./server
./shared
```

What i want is being able to compile a fat jars consisting of client+shared+dependencies of both and respective for server.

I have [this](https://gist.github.com/SealOfTime/547909b446d5085291d39080cdfd1b8a) build.gradle for a root project and empty build scripts for all subprojects, but i am unable to locate task :shadowJar for :client subproject. Executing `gradle :client:shadowJar` results in

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> *What went wrong:
> Task 'shadowJar' not found in root project 'client'.

How do i make the task :client:shadowJar work as i expect it to? Or how do i do this multi-project build? I have also thought of doing a separate tasks for a root project as you can see in build.gradle i've provided, but i did not understand, what i should do with the task to behave in requested manner. Appreciate any advice and solution for a problem that i've occured!

Comment: `Task 'shadowJar' not found in root project 'client'.` it looks like `client` project is considered as the **Root project** :  is this normal ?

Comment: Umm, no it's not, i must have messed up the settings.gradle of the client subproject.
Edit: No, it is the way Intellij Idea executes gradles tasks for subprojects